# Is there a solution for setting up android emulator in AMD E-450 CPU?

Tags: android, mobile, emulation, device, android-virtual-device

I am facing problem to run my android emulator integrated in android studio. When I try to run, it says the AVD process has terminated. Bellow is the the error:

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_33 has terminated

I am using AMD E-450 APU with radeon (tm) processor

I've tried to check Hyper-V, virtual machine platfrom and windows hypervisor platfrom, but the issue persists. The issue message is:Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Comment: Since this is a pretty old and low-end CPU, what is the size of the system RAM, and are you using HDD or SSD? Low RAM combined with HDD can mean it takes way too long for the emulator to start

Comment: Using SSD would help tremendously, especially since Android Studio will keep writing and reading itty bitty files all the time which simply isn't what HDD is supposed to do, and you also need large RAM both to handle the resource-hungry Android Studio itself and for the emulator (in itself can take 2 GB, you can lower it but in turn the emulator itself would crawl), but then the CPU itself can be a bottleneck.

Comment: Being a laptop, you can't easily upgrade the CPU, so if you use the emulator because you don't have an Android device or it's not on the latest version, you might find it easier to just buy a proper Android device, roughly $70 bucks for cheaper brand with Android 13, you can probably save more by selecting a second-hand model supported by LineageOS that also has support for Android 14.

Comment: My RAM size is 8GB and I am using SSD of 480GB

Comment: The hardware is far too weak. Years ago i used Genymotion as emulator for AMD, because of the official virtualization was only for Intel. It was free then, bur now they want much money for it. Last week i made a new PC build and now the android emulator pops up after several seconds and is quite fast. They have now some sort of new virtualization driver which installed automatically with the last Studio and works with AMD. But my new build is far beyond your laptop specs : Ryzen 7 5700x , 32 GB RAM , RX 7600 8 GB GPU and a NVME as main disc with 5000 GB/s read and 3000 GB/s write speeds.